# ngResource + 401 error handling: Expected response either an array or an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using the following code with ngResource to retrieve a list of objects:

```
    // Create the 'articles' service
    angular.module('articles').factory('Articles', ['$resource', function($resource) {

        // Use the '$resource' service to return an article '$resource' object
        return $resource('../api/admins/:adminId/articles/:articleId', {
            adminId: '@adminId'
        }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });

    }]);
```

Articles are retrieved like so:

```
    $scope.list = function() {
        // Use the articles'query' method to send an appropriate GET request
        Articles.query(
            function(articles){
                $scope.data.articles= articles;
            },
            function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    };
```

When a user is logged in, all works fine: The client expects an array and that's what it gets.

But after a while when the login timed out,  the server will return a 401 error with an object instead of an array. In fact, this is EXACTLY what is supposed to happen, but Angular throws the following error:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. 
Expected response to contain an array but got an object
```

The same problem occurs when a user retrieves a page that is forbidden (403).

Is there a way to resolve 401 and 403 request errors without getting an actual javascript error in Angular?

Comment: try to add `isArray: false` at your $resource request right after `method: 'your method'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query action of $resource by default expects an array to be returned from the server (see the docs).

You could use the transformResponse option for the query action to compensate for this like so:

```
return $resource('../api/admins/:adminId/articles/:articleId', {
        adminId: '@adminId'
    }, {
    update: {
        method: 'PUT'
    },
    query: {
        transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
            if(!angular.isArray(data)) {
                return new Array(data);
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

Of course it would be much better to handle errors using the error callback or with an interceptor

Comment: Thanx Sandhje, his works like a charm! :) (I will have a look at the interceptor as well).

Comment: Sandhje - could you please post an example with interceptor?